# Is there a way to rename "themes" directory name?

Tags: customization

By defining TEMPLATEPATH, STYLESHEETPATH, WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL merely affect the naming changes to wp-content.

Is there any way to redefine the theme path and plugin path, so the new path can propagate through function calls such as get_options or bloginfo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For themes you can use [`register_theme_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_theme_directory) function to add additional directories for WP to be aware of. I don't think I ever seen this used in practice, so not sure if there are any complications possible.

For plugins you can define `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WP_PLUGIN_URL` constants in `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `wp-content` folder which changes the plugin and theme dir. To do this you put change the folder location and put these two lines in your wp-config.php file:

```
define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR','/full/path/to/your/content/dir');
define ('WP_CONTENT_URL','http://example.com/full/path/to/your/content/dirs/url');
```

Just be aware that some plugins and themes are badly coded and may break because they are hard coded to look at the wp-content dir.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but my question was on how to continue using get_bloginfo and get_option after switching theme directory.